# sublime text 2 , emmet and html snippet not expanding

Tags: sublimetext2, emmet

I have read two answers on here for a similar issue, one mentions an example with colon, another mentions an example where there is a popup. I am new to emmet.  This one is just `html<tab>`

When emmet is disabled, I can see it expands `html<tab>` based on the file `html.sublime-snippet` so `html<tab>` becomes

```
<<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But with emmet enabled, when I do html it just expands to `<html></html>`  like any other tag.

I thought ok so it ignores html.sublime-snippet   and it uses its emmet snippets file of `snippets.json`

So I added an html line to the relevant looking part of the `snippets.json` file

I added this line to the end
`"html": "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n</head>\n<body>\n</body>\n</html>"`

```
"html": {
  "filters": "html",
  "profile": "html",
  "snippets": {
    "!!!":    "<!DOCTYPE html>",
    "!!!4t":  "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">",
    "!!!4s":  "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">",
    "!!!xt":  "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">",
    "!!!xs":  "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">",
    "!!!xxs": "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd\">",

    "c": "<!-- |${child} -->",
    "cc:ie6": "<!--[if lte IE 6]>\n\t${child}|\n<![endif]-->",
    "cc:ie": "<!--[if IE]>\n\t${child}|\n<![endif]-->",
    "cc:noie": "<!--[if !IE]><!-->\n\t${child}|\n<!--<![endif]-->",

    "html": "<html>\n<head>\n<title></title>\n</head>\n<body>\n</body>\n</html>"
},
```

But still when I type `html<tab>` it expands to `<html></html>` rather than the whole thing with the nested tags in between that it expands to when emmet is disabled .

Similarly with script  With emmet disabled it expands to `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`  Whereas with emmet enabled it only expands to `<script></script>`

Comment: What’s location of your `snippets.json` file?

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok `C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\Emmet\emmet\snippets.json`

Comment: Do you have the same effect with Ctrl-E shortcut? Do you see autocomplete popup when typing `html`?

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok  I spoke to somebody that knows emmet, and showed him some other behaviour, once after my edit, even html:5<tab> wasn't working, and he thought it was behaving wrongly and said to uninstall it and reinstall it, I did that and now it's functioning as emmet should. Ta

Comment: some of that may be normal.. and also bear in mind whether the file is .html/.html, or not.   With emmet enabled it seems you don't do html<tab> you do e.g. html:5<tab> And it seems with emmet, with script you have to do <script<tab> in order to get the type there.